# Setting Taxonomy value during itemadding

Tags: event-receivers, taxonomy

How can i set an taxonomyfield during an itemAdding event?

i've got a TaxonomyFieldValue created from my propertybag.

```
public override void ItemAdding(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{
     //Get site and list we are working on
     SPSite CurrentSite = properties.OpenSite();
     using (SPWeb web = properties.OpenWeb())
     {
         TaxonomySession taxonomySession = new TaxonomySession(CurrentSite);
         TaxonomyFieldValue taxvalue= new TaxonomyFieldValue(probertybagValue.ToString());
         properties.AfterProperties["MyField"] = taxvalue.ToString();
     }
     base.ItemAdding(properties);
}
```

Normaly i would use Taxonomy SetFieldValue option, but this can only use with an SPItem object, and we haven't that object during itemAdding

Answer (score 1):

i havent done this myself but why dont you implement the taxonomy:

```
    private void SetTaxononmyField(SPListItem newItem, TaxonomyFieldValue value, string fieldname)
    {
        TaxonomyField field = newItem.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName(fieldname) as TaxonomyField;
        if (field != null)
        {
            field.SetFieldValue(newItem, value);//Throws "Specified method is not supported" exception here
        }
    }
```

[TaxonomyField.SetFieldValue throws "Specified method is not supported" Exception](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/24840/taxonomyfield-setfieldvalue-throws-specified-method-is-not-supported-exception)

hope it helps :)

Comment: The reason why i didn't implement that is that there is no SPListItem object in the ItemAdding Event.

Comment: ? but you can!             using (SPWeb web = properties.Web)
             {
                 SPList list = web.Lists["ListName"];
                 SPListItemCollection listItemCollection = list.Items;
 
                foreach (SPListItem listItem in listItemCollection)
                 {
}}  from that you call the mthod that i stated ;)

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same requirement.
What I did was use the ItemAdded event and set it to run Synchronous.

Hope this helps,
Thanks